# Edits: Added Important Information to original question but Rejected

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

In Reference to [MySQL: View with Subquery in the FROM Clause Limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206062/mysql-view-with-subquery-in-the-from-clause-limitation)

I created an edit:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8313127

and was rejected due to:

```
Nico reviewed this 2 hours ago: Reject
Adding irrelevant information to the question

Degustaf reviewed this 2 hours ago: Approve

Félix Gagnon-Grenier reviewed this 2 hours ago: Reject
while this is posted by op in a comment, it would be best to ask her to add it to the question herself, the example might not represent the problem.

Tim Bezhashvyly reviewed this 3 hours ago: Reject
This modification has to be made by the author.
```

---

I made the edit to add the OP's query to the main question body because the SELECTED answer's first sentence and subsequent query refers directly to a query that the OP has written in a comment and the query does not exist anywhere else on that page.
Without digging through the comments in other people's answers, you will not be able to find the query that the SELECTED answer is based off of.
After seeing someone else add a comment to the SELECTED answer, asking about where the query that the answer is referring to is, I decided to add the query for the better of everyone.

I was rejected and it seems that the general "rule" is that the OP must add that information himself (one person said its "irrelevant information" which I also doubt).
The only problem with this is that the OP had originally posted this question in 2008. What happens if the OP never updates the question with his query? His question/answer essentially becomes useless.
Is this something that is okay with the community?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO, the edit was relevant. It does improve the question, and as it is taken form an OP's comment, it cannot *conflicts with author's intent*.

The problem, is that the reviewers *by default* only see the question outside of its context. I generally look at the real page when I'm in doubt facing a review, but I admit it takes some time, and *as it is not in the default interface* reviewer are not expected to do it.

In that particular case, you explicitely said that you took the query from a comment, so I would have approve it, and IMHO other reviewers should have too. But you know, we are all mere humans and do not always take the right decision. I must even admit that if I had reviewed it after 2 other crapy suggestions just before shutting down computer to go to bed, I might not have taken the necessary time to go through comments and reject it, saying as other that such an edit should be done by the author.

For completeness, the edit has now been committed again by Deduplicator

Comment: =( i dont get credit for my first useful edit haha.

Comment: I also did not know how the process goes for peer reviewing edits so i had no idea that they only see a specific portion of the question and it makes sense that some people will not pay as much attention, but... shouldn't they?
especially in my situation where I stated that it came from a comment...
With editing, comes responsibility. For instance, I am too lazy to do research on the question, so I deem myself unworthy of peer reviewing edits and making judgements.

Answer (score 3):

I would have rejected it. The SQL statement you added was from a comment to an answer far down on the page, and it was added in the form of "OK, so how would you write this SQL statement?". It's not clear that it should be part of the original question from the available context that you have when reviewing edits. You may have seen it when reading the question and it's answers, but it's not there in the edit review, and expecting everyone to visit the actual question and review all of the content when reviewing edits is just asking too much.

Comment: Well, the accepted answer, obvious at first glance, doesn't work without unearthing that comment, so it's not as dire as you make it look. I concede it needed a better summary, and a link to that comment though.

Comment: @Deduplicator: But that's not visible from the edit review. It *is* that dire - you don't see that information from that dialog, and have to visit the question to see it. (You can see it yourself - review some edits, and see what detail you have available while doing so.) If every edit review required a visit to the question itself and a careful review of each answer and every comment to those answers in order to decide if anything is there that is relevant, no edits would ever get approved. A comment to the original question (with a link to the relevant comment) would have been better.

Comment: `expecting everyone to visit the actual question and review all of the content when reviewing edits is just asking too much.` Is this really asking too much? The OP has said clearly in the revision comment, so the reviewer should confirm accordingly. (Note that I don't particularly agree or disagree with the reason why the suggested edit is rejected - I only disagree with the statement above).

Comment: @KenWhite The problem is that if you can review edits that also mean that you don't need to submit them and you can edit directly. So most people have no idea what the reviewers see.

Comment: There's no way it's "asking too much" to expect every reviewer "to visit the actual question and review all of the content when reviewing edits", at least when the edit summary mentions pulling information in from comments. It's also perfectly practical in most cases to do a quick check, and unless it's a very subtle thing, even posts that are outside one's area of expertise are usually straightforward enough to check correctly. What's more, the objection raised, that it's information buried in comments, is precisely why this sort of edit is so important!

Comment: i also believe that the purpose of reviewing edits is to ensure quality of the content, and for someone to take the task of reviewing and ensuring quality, i feel it should be a requirement that they expect to do SOME level of detective work in order to truly ensure the quality of the content and the edit.
its like: at any company, if you are tasked with reviewing engineering change requests (essentially an edit to a standard), you are expected to do a complete analysis on all potential effects before committing or rejecting any changes.

Comment: @Nathan: Knock yourself out. Just for fun, visit **every** question/answer for every edit review you do, and read every single comment, answer, and comment to answers on that post before passing judgement on the suggested edit. While you do your 2 or 3 per hour and try to be absolutely perfect in your evaluation, I'll do my 20 or 30 and make an occasional mistake that can be corrected. Do so for an hour every day for 30 days, and we'll see how many edits each of us can get done in that month. I'll wager that mine with the rare mistake outweighs the fewer (also with rare mistakes).

Comment: @agentprovocateur: OK. How many edit reviews have you participated in? Certainly the purpose of reviewing is to ensure quality, but it's not designed to do an absolute fact check of every single edit, taking into consideration every answer, comment, or the daily weather where you're sitting to do the reviews. But same offer to you as to Nathan above. Go for it.

Comment: @KenWhite: I ***do*** visit every post for suggested edits *with a summary that specifies the edit was drawn from a comment*… and even many of those that look like they're making that sort of change, but don't actually specify where it's from, just in case they forgot. Most days, I review not merely 20 suggested edits, but 60+, since I skip the majority of those I review. So when I say "this is what should be done, it's practical", I'm not just blowing hot air. This is already what I do.

Comment: @Nathan: That's great. Kudos to you. I do a considerable amount of edits and reviews as well, in addition to answering quite a few questions or commenting to a poster with suggestions to improve them, and at least come close to my allocation of close and question/answer votes every single day. If you choose to spend your day instead on painstakingly reviewing every single question/answer you see in the review queues instead, that's your choice.

Comment: @KenWhite: Since very few suggested edits depend on anything in comments, this is not really very difficult or time-consuming; I spend no more than about half an hour reviewing suggested edits in a day, although it's spread out a bit as they become available. This is not something that consumes an entire day.

Comment: @Nathan: Ok. In regards to the question that prompted this post. If the comment containing the SQL is deleted (because comments are transitory in nature, after all, and can be cleaned up at any time), where is the reference that shows that this edit didn't just come out of thin air? Instead of an edit to the question, IMO the poster here should have left a comment to the question that included a link to the comment  containing the SQL and a request for the poster to include it in their question. It would have notified the question's poster and informed future readers of its presence.

Comment: @KenWhite: The reference *should be* that three reviewers checked the existence of the comment *at the time of the edit* and verified that it was correct; anything else risks data loss if the OP is absent. It's not just their question anymore; questions should be maintained by the community wherever practical. (Choosing Improve Edit and entering a summary that indicates having checked the suggestion and adding a bit more editing is probably the best way to assure this at present, but competent reviewers approving for the right reasons is, ideally, quite enough.)

Comment: @KenWhite: After all, who's to say the second comment won't be cleaned up the same as the first? If someone asked a question seven years ago, there's no guarantee they'll still be around. Or even seven months ago. That's fine; SO can handle things without them.

Comment: @Nathan: If you're OK with others adding content to *your* questions without giving you the chance to do so yourself, even adding content that you didn't  (but saying came from an unlinked comment), that's fine. I don't agree it's appropriate to do so. Adding major content to a question that wasn't put there by the poster can (often quite negatively) impact their reputation. In this case, it *might* have been a valid edit. Three reviewers said not, and the edit was rejected. Anyway, we seem to be at an impasse here; you're clearly not going to change your mind, and I'm not changing mine. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: If I'm careless enough to put important information only in comments, I would certainly hope others would recognize the importance of that and make the edit, which I would then be informed of (in time to approve or reject a suggestion, or rollback a 2ker's immediate edit). If the information is coming from random guesses, that's a whole nother story, but that's not the case here: it's the asker's own comment. I should hope they'd recognize the query they're (thinking of) using!

Comment: @KenWhite I am not saying you NEED to visit EVERY SINGLE question/answer for each edit you review. I am saying, when the case calls for it (such as but not limited to: when the edit refers to a comment), the reviewer should not have a problem with visiting the question to do "SOME level of detective work", however much is appropriate for that edit, before deciding to take action. Basically saying: pay a bit more attention to details. How can the community be so strict on quality of questions but then be so lax on the quality of edit reviews?

Comment: @agentprovocateur: Your failing to get a single edit approved is not an indicator that the *community is so lax* on anything. Broad statements of a general condition need to be backed up with data. Where is the proof of this being *so lax on the quality of edit reviews* other than your single example? Perhaps you're taking the importance of your single lack of approval too personally. :-) I assure you there little risk you'll experience any actual physical trauma, vast psychological damage, loss of hair, or risk of death from it.

Comment: This is basically bad data in the SE system, and when reviewers reject good edits by overlooking details and not paying some attention to detail (where and when needed), they are in essence confirming that the bad data is good and should stay in SE the way it is.
You may argue that there are simply too many edits to review in that way. However, in my opinion NO ACTION is better than NEGATIVE ACTION, especially in the case of data and information. SE needs MORE reviewers doing QUALITY work, instead of encouraging light skimming and getting thru as much QUANTITY of reviews as you can.

Comment: @KenWhite I will admit my experience with reviews and reviewers is very limited here so I may be drawing too much on this experience.
but I think its very indicative when it happens so quickly and when comments left on my peer review show little sign of truly understanding the question of "why the edit was made".

Comment: @agentprovocateur: I'll repeat it again: Claims of a far reaching negative pattern of behavior here need to be backed up with DATA (since you seem to feel the need to SHOUT). If in the process of doing (at least) hundreds of thousands of edit reviews by many **thousands** of reviewers an occasional incorrect rejection (or approval) occurs, that's acceptable. As I said, there's little risk of physical harm coming to the individual. SHOUTING accusations of a wide-spread pattern of poor review behavior that doesn't exist is simply wrong. Live with the single (*perhaps* incorrect) one and move on.

Comment: (continued): There are many questions here (and on the uber-Meta) related to minor individual (or system) mistakes. When you can prove that you're infallible and *never* make a single mistake, you can accuse others who do of being imperfect. Until then, learn to accept that mistakes happen, particularly when dealing with the large volume of data here and the large number of individuals (with various experience, language skills, technical knowledge, etc) involved. Those quite occasional mistakes (as a percentage) can be expected; they don't indicate the *community is lax* by any means.

Comment: lol im not SHOUTING. im just EMPHASIZING.
of course theres a percentage of failure for anything and everything. i think its our job to try to act on these failures rather than to ignore them because "they happen". These are opportunities for improvement that should be explored.
I never said i never make mistakes. What I did imply, however, is that I try to keep myself away from situations where I would be more prone to making errors. e.g. if i dont have time for properly reviewing a document, i do not try.

Comment: @agentprovocateur: You can add *emphasis* in **several ways** without SHOUTING (typing in CAPS). You're not listening-maybe I should **SHOUT**. :-) A single (possible) wrong edit review doesn't mean anything needs to be *improved* (unless the improvement is to raise the rep requirement for both proposing edits and reviewing them, so that the users have more experience here; I don't think that's what you want). Another solution could be to *not approve edits that substantially alter the question*. Oh, right - that's what happened here with a reject reason added to improve edit quality.

Comment: @KenWhite lol how about this. my LIMITED EXPERIENCE with questions on SE leads me to believe that the community holds questions to a high degree of quality. my LIMITED EXPERIENCE with peer reviews leads me to believe the community is more lax than with questions. Its very simple, if I EXPERIENCED something good, I would recognize it (as seen from recognition of holding question quality to a high standard followed by good execution).

Comment: I experienced something not ideal and I am saying that THIS CASE IS A PROBLEM. it may not be indicative of EVERY SINGLE REVIEW but this particular case HAPPENED. i choose not to ignore it because it may happen AGAIN. is that a bad thing? sorry but from what i can see, what happened here is not a good example to use for ANY reason besides "what went wrong".